# Is "non-life-threatening" punctuated correctly with two hyphens?

Tags: punctuation

The news reporter said, “The victim's injuries were *non-life-threatening*.” [Verbatim quote, so I cannot alter the wording to say "...were not life-threatening".]

Is *non-life-threatening* correctly punctuated with two hyphens as shown? Or should it be *nonlife-threatening* in this particular context?

Comment: I was about to recommend you to have a look on Google to see what people seem to use. After checking, I won't. The bound morpheme _non_  is the negator for life-threatening here, so 'life-threatening' is more coherent. This does not come across with nonlife-threatening, which would seem to imply a threat to non-life. Leaving _non_ stranded doesn't work either as it is a bound morpheme, a prefix not a word (in English). I'd use the two hyphens.

Comment: I searched Google Books and encountered a multiplicity of contradictions. I am in total agreement with you, Mr Ashworth (ie two hyphens).

Answer (score 2):

This is one case where it's onerous to look at dozens/hundreds of entries directly within Google Books, but it's relatively easy to see what most people do by looking at Google Ngrams...

[image: Ngram showing "non-life-threatening" way ahead of alternatives]

The pros and cons are covered perfectly well by Edwin's comment against the question, but with such a strong preference for "non-life-threatening" as indicated above, it's pretty obvious which one you should go for.

Comment: Restores one's faith in Ngrams.

Comment: @Edwin: Yeah - it reflects what I would have expected, in that as you commented, *non* is very much a "bound morpheme". So those people who think two hyphens is a bit much are more likely to keep the first one rather than the second.

Answer (score 2):

The [U.S. Government Printing Office Style Manual (PDF)](http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/GPO-STYLEMANUAL-2008/pdf/GPO-STYLEMANUAL-2008.pdf), in paragraph 6.32
(page 120 of the file, which displays a page number of 103), says
“Use a hyphen or hyphens … to avoid ambiguity.”, and gives “non-tumor-bearing tissue”
and “non-civil-service position” as examples of correct hyphen usage. 
“non-life-threatening injuries” seems to be consistent with those examples.